# Android DrawerLayout second actionbar does not dim the screen when button is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have created a program, I have the base nav bar extended like so:

```
public class navBar extends AppCompatActivity {}
```

The navbar code itself is too long to include, but it sets a toolbar, and sets a navbar and works great when I use it in most parts of my app.

However, when I try to add another navbar in the extended class it does something odd, when I press the points of interest button to open it and it runs this code:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.POI)
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

It opens the drawer as requested, but leaves no dimming on the screen. Like so:
[image: broken]

When I close the screen with the back button/points of interest button for example it lags a bit, dragging the white slowly but closes.

Even worse, when I had opened the drawer with a 
However, when I use my finger to drag from right to left to open the drawer, it opens and functions perfectly.

[image: functional]

Because my map class is rather long as well, I've tried to include only the important code:

```
 public class Map2 extends navBar {

private Toolbar toolbar;

ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_maptest, frameLayout);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_base_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
    ) {


        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            mDrawerList.clearChoices();
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        }
    };


    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


    mNavigationDrawerItemTitles= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
mNavigationDrawerItemTitles= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
POIAdapter_without_image adapter2 = new POIAdapter_without_image(this, R.layout.points_of_interest, drawerItem2);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter2);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());



}
    @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    actionBarDrawerToggleChild.syncState();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_skill_view, menu);
    return true;
}

    public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Edit:
Whenever I select a point on the points of interest list, the dragging white line can be seen here moments after the actual drawer has closed:
[image: weird_white_bar]

The black flash mentioned appears to be android both setting the dim and unsetting the dim as soon as I close the drawer.

This has thoroughly confused me for a few nights now. Thank you all!

Comment: why you are finding mDrawerLayout object again and again

Comment: I just haven't cleaned the code yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the answer was to call:

```
final FrameLayout mapView = (FrameLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_maptest, frameLayout);
```

and when I wanted to find anything use

```
 mDrawerLayout2 = (DrawerLayout) mapView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

for example.

it was then necessary to call

```
mDrawerLayout2.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
```

rather than

```
mDrawerLayout2.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

To obtain the needed functionality

Answer (score 1):

you *setDrawerShadow* to cast shadow to drawer

```
drawer_layout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```

**Update :**

> drawer_shadow is .png file you put in drawable folder.
>
> START : when drawer opens from left side.
>
> END : when drawer opens from right side

Comment: But why then would it flash black whenever I tap anywhere to close the navigation drawer after opening it with a button?

Comment: sorry I didnt get your question...can you elaborate

Comment: The application will flash black momentarily (as though it is setting the proper darkness for when the drawer is open) whenever I close the drawer after it was opened with the button. The button appears to be the issue here. Whenever the button is pressed the drawer opens with no dim, when the drawer is closed afterwords, the screen flashes black and closes the drawer. I need to fix the black flash as well as the lack of dimming intially

Comment: do not set `setDrawerShadow` at button onclick...set on at `oncreate()`

Comment: I haven't been setting drawershadow anywhere. And it worked before I attempted to use a base/extended class.

Comment: I think the issue lies in: mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList); This is something I had to change from DrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END); While I used the latter before in my code that had both nav bars in one class, when I use it now it complains that drawerlayout is null. But I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: it complains even when I set the line before it:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity RIGHT

Comment: Maybe this is due to the drawer not being directly in the activity, but inflated like so getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_maptest, frameLayout); where the right navbar is in maptest. But then, how do I grab it?

Comment: as i can see your drawer is on right side and shadow is on left side...so your `setDrawerShadow` should be on left side i.e `GravityCompat.START` and your drawer gravity should be on right side..i.e `drawer_layout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);`

Comment: Although these are all true, these unfortunately didn't help in my case